# Split the second column based on the first column

Tags: linux

I have two columns like this:

```
cluster22717    GO:0005737,GO:0007049,GO:0051301
```

how can I transform it to this:

```
cluster22717    GO:0005737
cluster22717    GO:0007049
cluster22717    GO:0051301
```

I should also mention that this is a line from a file with thousands of lines like this which the second column have a different number of elements.
Thanks in advance,
Pezhman Safdari

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use some loops, see a sample below,

**Input file : sample.txt**

```
cluster22717    GO:0005737,GO:0007049,GO:0051301
cluster22717    GO:0005738,GO:0007041,GO:0051304,GO:0051307
cluster22717    GO:0005739,GO:0007042,GO:0051305,GO:0005737,GO:0007046
cluster22717    GO:0005740,GO:0007043,GO:0051306,GO:0005738,GO:0007041,GO:0051304
```

**Script:**

```
while read line
do
    var1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')                           # assign first field to var1
    Arrayvals=($(echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/,/ /g')) # create an array from second filed

    for (( i=0; i < ${#Arrayvals[@]} ; i++ ))  # iterate the array using a for loop , ${#Arrayvals[@]} -> gives the length of array
    do
        echo "${var1}    ${Arrayvals[${i}]}"   # echo in desired format
    done

done < sample.txt
```

**Output:**

```
cluster22717   GO:0005737
cluster22717   GO:0007049
cluster22717   GO:0051301
cluster22717   GO:0005738
cluster22717   GO:0007041
cluster22717   GO:0051304
cluster22717   GO:0051307
cluster22717   GO:0005739
cluster22717   GO:0007042
cluster22717   GO:0051305
cluster22717   GO:0005737
cluster22717   GO:0007046
cluster22717   GO:0005740
cluster22717   GO:0007043
cluster22717   GO:0051306
cluster22717   GO:0005738
cluster22717   GO:0007041
cluster22717   GO:0051304
```

Hope this will do some help,

Comment: Yes, this will do. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

with sed

```
while read line;do
    left=$(echo $line|grep -oE '^[^ ]+ +')  #the left part + a blank
    echo $line |
        grep -oE '[^ ]+$' |                 #take the right part
        sed -r "s/([^,]+),?/$left\1\n/g" |  #prefix every GO::, with the left part and go back to line
        grep 'c' |                          #remove the empty line added by the very last group
        tee -a output.txt
done<other.txt
```

output

```
cluster22717 GO:0005737
cluster22717 GO:0007049
cluster22717 GO:0051301
cluster22717 GO:0005738
cluster22717 GO:0007041
cluster22717 GO:0051304
cluster22717 GO:0051307
cluster22717 GO:0005739
cluster22717 GO:0007042
cluster22717 GO:0051305
cluster22717 GO:0005737
cluster22717 GO:0007046
cluster22717 GO:0005740
cluster22717 GO:0007043
cluster22717 GO:0051306
cluster22717 GO:0005738
cluster22717 GO:0007041
cluster22717 GO:0051304
```